# find data if at least 3 character match

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I try to make mongodb query which show result if at least 3 character match.

my code

```
    var q = req.param('q');        
    var regex = new RegExp(q, "[\w]{3,}");
    user.find({name : regex}, function(err, products_search) {
    }
```

But it show error

```
Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor '[w]{3,}'
```

Comment: Try `"\w{3,}"`... This will work.

Comment: What is `q`, and why are you passing it to the regex constructor? [The constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax) takes a pattern, and then, optionally, some flags.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  use `/[\w]{3,}/g` or  `/\w{3,}/g`  with modifier.

```
 var re = /[\w]{3,}/g;
    var str = 'sfsf sdfds fdg fd fgdf gfd fd ';
    var m;

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
    }
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI5mK5/1)